# Problems loading more than 1 form - VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I searched over the Stackoverflow and Google about solution for my problem but no way! so it's the time to ask my own question.

I'm making a big project using C# and VB.net (not our topic -_-)

I opened this question to ask about VB.net problem

I'm trying to load a lot of forms but in the same time, hide the previous form!

Firstly, look here on **Form1**:

```
Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
        If Label1.Text = "Setting profile.dat=Roblox.AuthAccess ..." Then
            Form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
End Sub
```

This is a timer, which detect if Label1's Text is "Setting profile.dat=Roblox.AuthAccess ..." it must show Form2 and then close Form1 (THIS IS WORKING PERFECTLY) :-)

**Form2**:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString().Contains("home") Then
            Me.Hide()
            Form3.Show()
        End If
End Sub
```

This will detect if "**WebBrowser1**"'s URL does contain "home" then it will hide Form2 and show Form3 (AND HERE THE PROBLEM STARTED!!!)

***Problem is***: It shows Form3 then after 2 seconds, Form2 come back again (now both are opened once) and they're opening and closing forever (I close them by going to Task Manager and ending "vshost32.exe")

**Form3**:

```
Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Form4.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What on earth has this to do with c# then as all this is vb code.

Comment: Is the timer firing again?  If so you can disable it in Timer4_Tick or set autoreset = false.

Comment: @JoeC, wrong `Timer`. `AutoReset` is a member of `System.Timers.Timer`, not `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. You would need to set `Enabled` to `False` or, preferably, call `Stop`.

Comment: Yeah. Sounds like the timer is firing again. Set Enabled = False before hiding the form, so it doesn't fire again.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the heads up on forms.timer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - How can I call "Stop" ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, stopping timers is still not a stable solution and disabling them are more better.

Just replace `Timer4.Stop()` with `Timer4.Enabled = False` .

Comment: +1 THNX VERY MUCH PROTLD !!! timerX.stop() return RenderError now it was working fine.. .. . . ...........

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @jmcilhinney :)

I never thought about stopping every "Timer" after it's job had finished!

Just replaced Timer4_Tick with:

```
Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
        If Label1.Text = "Setting profile.dat=Roblox.AuthAccess ..." Then
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
            Timer4.Stop()
        End If
End Sub
```

So at last, I fixed that by adding **Timer4.Stop()** .